# Python Indentation bug?

Tags: python, indentation

I have the this code:

```
import numpy
import random
import pylab
from ps3b import *

def AvgWithDrug(numViruses, maxPop, maxBirthProb, clearProb, resistances, mutProb, numTrials, delay):

  viruses = []
  timeSteps = delay + 300
  print 'timeSteps = ', timeSteps

  for i in range(numViruses):
      viruses += [ResistantVirus(maxBirthProb, clearProb, resistances, mutProb)]

  avg = [0] * timeSteps
  print 'len avg[] =', len(avg)
  hola = []
  last = 0

  for j in range(numTrials):
      patient = TreatedPatient(viruses, maxPop)
      for i in range(timeSteps):
          if i == 150:
              patient.addPrescription('guttagonol')
          if i == 150 + delay:
              patient.addPrescription('grimpex')
          avg[i] += patient.update()

      new = avg[timeSteps - 1]
      print new - last
      hola += [new - last]
      last = new

  for i in range(timeSteps):
      avg[i] = avg[i]/ float(numTrials)
      print avg[i]


  print 'len avg[] =', len(avg)
```

Of course you cannot run it without knowing how to attach my class definitions.

But the issue when I run it is that last statement is like it is inside the above for loop. `print avg[i]` should be executed `timeSteps` times, and last `print 'len avg[] =', len(avg)` should be executed once.

It doesn't happen; the output shows me `print avg[i]`,  `print 'len avg[] =', len(avg)` over and over again through the `timeSteps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. Most of your code is indented with spaces, but a few lines have tabs, including the line that seems to be indented too far. Python treats a tab like Notepad does, as enough spaces to reach the next 8-space indentation level. Run your code with the `-tt` option to get Python to notify you of things like this, turn on "show whitespace" in your editor if it has that option, and change those tabs to spaces.

Comment: hmm, I thought that... and tryed to execute a macro to convert all tabs to spaces and aparently didn't work. Right now, I'm working with a previous template which works fine. I'll try in a momment enabling white spaces view and look for any tab misfit

Comment: yeap, thanks... I enabled the white spaces to whatch them... and found the misfits tabs. Now it run fine